# Mirror drives on Exchange 2k3 server, larger drives than OS partition RAID ok?

Tags: raid, exchange-2003, mirror

I have an Exchange 2k3 server that uses a backup process that is at times unreliable. Part of the process is to nightly truncate those transactions logs (we receive ALOT of email). Currently I have two 146GB disks that are running in a mirror configuration just for my transaction logs.

I check the process daily to make sure it works doing its job, if its not a reboot usually kicks things back off within a day. However if it happens on a weekend and a few days accumulate before I can notice and reboot (I need some time off!), then HD space gets real low on those transaction log drives.

The 146GB drives used in that mirror are the same size drives as the RAID that is powering the main OS partition.

I'm thinking of order LARGER drivers for the mirror, pulling the exist drives out installing the two new drives as the new mirror for the transaction logs. This'll give me more time to notice there is an issue and correct it.

This server will be going away next year so this is really just a stop gap. I've never seen multiple size drives used before and in my mind it doesn't seem like it would be an issue since its two separate "arrays" but I wanted to bounce the idea off here...

Comment: You can fill up 146GB of Exchange 2003 logs within a few days??  Wow.

Comment: Yeah I've gotta try to figure out what's causing this growth...

Comment: The size of the drives in the disk array that you use for the transaction logs is unrelated to the size of the drives in any other disk array.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be a problem. You can mix and match drive sizes as needed for things like this.